# Why am i getting a 403 forbidden when using a img tag?

Tags: html, image, http-status-code-403

When trying to use

```
<img src="../Ginger.jpeg" />
```

I am getting a 403 error.

Here is the page which is requesting:

http://laponderosakennels.com/beagles/memories/ginger/index.html

What is going on here am I just tired?

Comment: http://laponderosakennels.com/beagles/memories/ seems like `jpEg` are not working, others are. Have you checked the permissions are set to read?

Comment: Directly navigating to the image also gets a 403. Sounds like a server configuration problem. Check your file permissions.

Comment: so do something like chmod? what am looking for?

Comment: I think Moak is on to something. Check your apache config and make sure it's set up to serve .jpeg files as image/jpg, since it's only the files with that extension that are failing.

Comment: Yes, `chmod` can fix the problem if you discover that it's permissions, but first you should `ls -lh` the directory to see if the permissions for the failing file are any different than the others. If it's the same, that's not the problem.

Comment: By permissions I meant both permissions and ownership; feel free to `chown` as necessary too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you look at http://laponderosakennels.com/beagles/memories/Ginger.jpeg it throws a 403 error.. there is a permission issue for the same.

The problem is probably cos you are referring to the wrong file.. i took the liberty of looking at your folder structure and you are referring to **ginger.jpeg** which has a permission issue and there is a file **ginger.jpg** that works fine.

Also make sure you refer to the file correctly.. i.e `ginger.jpg`

Comment: There is a *Ginger.jpeg* as well. So this is a permissions issue, not a filename issue.

Answer (score 5):

This can also be caused by using hotlinking protection. So if hotlinking protection is used, make sure that the URL for your website is added to the white list. Also keep in mind that www.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com are considered two different URLs.

Comment: wasted 2 agonizing days due to this. your answer saved me further agony.

Answer (score 2):

403 stands for permission denied. You need to check the permissions for "Ginger.jpeg".

Comment: What should I change them to?

Comment: The user the webserver process runs as needs to be able to read the file, and you need to make sure there is nothing in the server config is blocking access elsewhere.